# Can I selfdestruct a smart contract without the selfdestruct function being implemented?

Tags: selfdestruct

is it possible to selfdestruct a smart contract which I have deployed even though the ***selfdestruct(address)*** function is not implemented in the code?

Thank you

Comment: I'd say the linked answer mostly answers the question but just to make it clear: most likely you can't, unless you have implemented some delegate functionality which allows another contract to call an arbitrary function (such as selfdestruct) inside your contract

Comment: Thank you this is what I was looking for. So it looks like there is no way for me to destroy the contracts which I have already deployed. I find it interesting, because it means that these "useless" contracts will consume blockchain space forever, which is quite "inefficient".